# What is the difference between defining a method with the `where` clause vs omitting it in Julia?

Tags: methods, julia, dispatch

For example:

```
foo(x::Real) = x ^ 2
bar(x::R) where {R<:Real} = x ^ 2
```

Both seem to have similar performance, which seems to imply that the compiler is creating specialized code for, e.g., `Int` vs `Float64`. So is the only difference that in the latter, `R` can be used/referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are the same:

```
julia> foo(x::Real) = x ^ 2
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> bar(x::R) where {R <: Real} = x ^ 2
bar (generic function with 1 method)

julia> code_lowered
code_lowered (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> code_lowered(foo)
1-element Vector{Core.CodeInfo}:
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Main.:^
│   %2 = Core.apply_type(Base.Val, 2)
│   %3 = (%2)()
│   %4 = Base.literal_pow(%1, x, %3)
└──      return %4
)

julia> code_lowered(bar)
1-element Vector{Core.CodeInfo}:
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Main.:^
│   %2 = Core.apply_type(Base.Val, 2)
│   %3 = (%2)()
│   %4 = Base.literal_pow(%1, x, %3)
└──      return %4
)
```

The difference in fact is none in the code initially generated, even if you take out the restriction to Real:

```
julia> baz(x) = x ^ 2
baz (generic function with 1 method)

julia> code_lowered(baz)
1-element Vector{Core.CodeInfo}:
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Main.:^
│   %2 = Core.apply_type(Base.Val, 2)
│   %3 = (%2)()
│   %4 = Base.literal_pow(%1, x, %3)
└──      return %4
)
```

However, there will be a difference in the just-in-time compilation. If you supply a String argument, only `baz("abc")` will work -- the other two will not pass the JIT step because "abc" is not a `Real`.

TLDNR: The difference in foo and bar is only in the syntax.

Comment: This apply to the `foo` wnd `bar` functions, can we day that it generalise to any function?